# Upgrade activity NiFi 1.15.3 to 1.18

Tags: apache-nifi, upgrade

In Versions 1.15.3 has Flow Configuration in flow.xml.gz,and we need to upgrade it into 1.18.0 which has flow.json.gz
so how we are going to upgrade this one!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have issues with the migration as NiFi still supports the backward compatibility of XML files.

This is defined by the property `nifi.flow.configuration.file*` within the `nifi.properties` file

This is a legacy property. Older versions of NiFi used an XML-formatted file to store the flow configuration. However, newer versions use a JSON representation. In order to maintain backward compatibility of flows and still load flows developed using older versions of NiFi, upon startup, NiFi will use the nifi.flow.configuration.json.file first. If the file exists, it will be used. However, if it does not exist, NiFi will fall back to this property to determine the XML version of the file and use it.

You can find more information for the migration [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#upgrade-recommendations)